# When first open camera I don't have permissions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problem with access to camera first time. I installed
 my app. Next go to scan to QR Code. I use to scan QR Code google vision. App show dialog, which show about the permissions, next click "Allow",but camera doesn't open. But I go back activity and go to activity which scan QR Code, camera open.

my AdnroidManifest.xml

my class

```
public class ScanQrCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(context));
    }

    private static final String TAG = "Barcode-reader";
    // intent request code to handle updating play services if needed.
    private static final int RC_HANDLE_GMS = 9001;
    // permission request codes need to be < 256
    private static final int RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM = 2;

    private DatabaseHandler helper;
    private TextView title_app;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;
    private CameraSourcePreview mPreview;
    private GraphicOverlay<BarcodeGraphic> mGraphicOverlay;
    String passwordString, eightChars, barcodeString, decodedBarcodeValue, OTP;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_qr_code);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
        title_app = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);


        helper = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay<BarcodeGraphic>) findViewById(R.id.graphicOverlay);
        eightChars = getIntent().getStringExtra("eightChars");
        passwordString = getIntent().getStringExtra("passwordString");

        int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            createCameraSource();
        } else {
            requestCameraPermission();
        }

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, R.string.zeskanuj_wygenerowany_kod, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        View mView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
            mTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        else
            mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        snackbar.show();

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.stage2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        Log.w(TAG, "Camera permission is not granted. Requesting permission");

        final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            return;
        }

        final Activity thisActivity = this;

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                        RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            }
        };

        findViewById(R.id.topLayout).setOnClickListener(listener);
        Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, "Aby móc wykryć Qr Koda potrzebny jest dostęp do kamery.",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.ok, listener)
                .show();

    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void createCameraSource() {

        boolean autoFocus = false;
        boolean useFlash = false;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
        BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(mGraphicOverlay);
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
                new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());

        barcodeFactory.setNewBarcodeListener(new BarcodeTrackerFactory.OnNewBarcodeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewItem(final Barcode item) {
                Log.d("BarcodeFound", "Found new barcode! " + item.rawValue);

                title_app.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


        if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational())

        {
            IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
            boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

            if (hasLowStorage) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
            }
        }

        CameraSource.Builder builder = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), barcodeDetector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(15.0f);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)

        {
            builder = builder.setFocusMode(
                    autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);
        }

        mCameraSource = builder
                .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                .

                        build();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startCameraSource();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mPreview != null) {
            mPreview.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPreview != null) {
            mPreview.release();
        }
    }

    private void startCameraSource() throws SecurityException {
        // check that the device has play services available.
        int code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
                getApplicationContext());
        if (code != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Dialog dlg =
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS);
            dlg.show();
        }

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            try {
                mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
                mCameraSource.release();
                mCameraSource = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the your Android version ?

Comment: my version Android 6.0.1

Comment: Then You have to take RunTime Permission for API 21

Comment: @EwelinaMaj My answer below should solve your problem. Let me know if you face any more issues

Comment: ok I will check

Answer (score 0):

In your code immplement the following method

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                boolean isPerpermissionForAllGranted = false;
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions.length==grantResults.length) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
                        if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                        }else{
                            isPerpermissionForAllGranted=false;
                        }
                    }

                    Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
                } else {
                    isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                }
                if(isPerpermissionForAllGranted){
                    // Fire here again for camera
                    createCameraSource();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

So what happens is When you fire the dialog for permission, you can implement the result method to come to know whether you were granted permission or not. So here you can check if the permission is granted for your permission request, You can again fire your method to open the camera.

Comment: what did you change and why?

Comment: Yep was adding that.

Comment: add it before posting

Comment: Yes it was a miss from my side as i clicked submit by mistake. Updated @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app.

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public boolean checkPermission()
{
   int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
   if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
   {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)) {
               AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
               alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
               alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
               alertBuilder.setMessage("Write calendar permission is necessary to write event!!!");
               alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
                   }
               });
               AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
               alert.show();
           } else {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
           }
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
```

References :
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
https://www.sitepoint.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-m-and-n/
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow